# Mongodb write performance/load primary vs secondary

Tags: mongodb

In a replicated Mongodb environment, is the write performance/load on the secondaries the same as the primaries? If so, or not, why?

Edit: By writes to the secondary I am referring to the automatic propagation of the writes from the primary to the secondary.

Edit2: To help guide the conversation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#multithreaded-replication might suggest that write performance from the primaries to the secondaries might be better since they are performed in `batch`.

Comment: You can not write on secondary nodes, only on primary

Comment: yes that is true but writes get propagated

Answer (score 0):

If by `load` you mean only `writes` in an isolated or off-peak system then it must be an uninteresting and similar `performance/write`. and almost who cares.  However, in a working system where you have concurrent reads and writes then no. because one can alter that `performance/readwrite` if you use a ['read preference'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) of "secondary" or "secondary preferred" (heck, anything but "primary"). Under this scenario a replica set with 11 secondaries and 1 primary one can clearly see that any single secondary has a fraction of cpu/memory/disk/etc competition not only disk contention than the single primary.  Recall that the default mode is brutal on the primary. here the secondaries exist only for redundancy vs high-availability.

> primary Default mode. All operations read from the current replica set
>   primary.

One can think of a RAID system whereby mirroring increases redundancy while striping increases performance. (True, not exactly the same mechanics but from the user's pov its a similar result in terms of reads. Sharding is closer to a RAID with striping) Using the default read preference of 'primary' one taps only into mirroring; using a read preference of 'secondary' you tap into the greater throughput.

Comment: Disk contention isn't really the correct term. Since all of these operations are happening within memory mapped files (with the mmapv1 storage engine), it is possible the is no disk contention at all. A more appropriate term would be "resource contention" since there are several places where contention can be happening depending on various factors such as: working set size, available memory, size of each operation being performed, indexes, type of operation being performed, etc.